# How to check if a specific attribute is valid ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have been looking for an out-of-the-box way to check if a specific attribute is valid for a certain model but I haven't found anything, I think is weird that `rails` do not provide a very easy way to check this.

note: I don't want to use `valid?` because that will run all the validations in my model. Let me know if I am missing anything, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

After looking for a couple of hours, I didn't find anything specific but I did come with a workaround to the problem. Let's say you have a model called **User** (which is quite common) and you want to validate that the *email* complies with the validations you have in place, below is a way to check only for that specific attribute.

```rb
user = User.new(email: 'foo!!!')
User.validators_on(:email).map{ |validator| validator.validate(user) } # apply the validator to the attribute
user.errors.full_messages # will return a list of all the errors found with the specified attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, the quickest solution to check one attribute would be:

```
user = User.new(email: 'wrongEmail')
user.validate(:email) => false or true
```

Comment: That would be wonderful, but that does not work like that. [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F)